# How to obtain ActiveMQConnection from ActiveMQConnectionFactory?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

How to obtain ActiveMQConnection from ActiveMQConnectionFactory in activemq5.12.  ? i am only getting a connection object from ActiveMQConnectionFactory  as below

```
      factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
            Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
```

My final goal is to set maximum redlivery attempts which can be set on ActiveMQConnection  object using setRediliveryPolicy .

Regards
Jayendra Bhatt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ActiveMQConnection** internally implements `javax.jms.connection` so you should be able to do something like

`ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) factory.createConnection();`

hope this helps!

Good luck!